# reading a text file in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have a text file with some data i would like to open the text file and copy data to text box fields in form, I would like do this in event procedure for click event of a button in the same form, I am using ms access 2007.

Text file is very simple it has one column with 6 rows

```
12
2.5
6.7
9.5
3.4
7.6
```

I would like put these number to fields in the form.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would lean towards "FileDialog" for selecting the text file, and then "FileSystemObject - Textstream" for reading through the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how to open a text file and copy a field into a field on your form

```
Dim MyStr1 as string
dim MyStr2 as string

Open "TESTFILE" For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)    ' Loop until end of file.
    Input #1, MyStr1, MyStr2
    me.txtStr1 = MyStr1
    me.txtStr2 = MyStr2
Loop
Close #1    ' Close file.
```

(the example loops through multiple rows, but you could equally well unroll the loop and do each row individually, as you might want to do - depending on how your text file is organised)

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733686%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: You know how i can open file browser dialog so that i can get user to open his file.

Comment: add to the knowledge base... post another question

Comment: @nman84 Look at my comment I posted yesterday, search for "FileDialog" this is the one for file open prompts.